# Nested route with :member

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I'm using rails3 and I have the following bit in my routing.rb:

```
resources :questions do
 resources :answers do
    get 'accept', :on => :member
 end
end
```

Now I'm trying to find how to use the auto-generated routing method.

I've used many variations of

```
questions_accepts_answers_path(@question,answer)
```

but none have worked yet.

As a side note, I am currently using

```
<%= link_to "Accept this answer", "/question/#{question.id}/answers/#{answer.id}/accept" %>
```

and the routing works as expected, I just want to use the proper methods

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried running `rake routes` from the command line (in the default directory of your rails app)?  It will give you a list of all the generated route helpers and their associated paths.  From this, it should be easy to figure out which path helper you are looking for.  If you are looking for a specific path, you may want to do something like `rake routes | grep question` or `rake routes | grep answer`.

Comment: Awesome, That's exactly what I was looking for. Sad I had to ask the question here to find out this ;)

Comment: It's alright, I remember having the same reaction when somebody told me about `rake routes` - good luck!